# Poetry unwanted access to packages beyond env

Tags: python-poetry

It was my understanding that the virtual env created by poetry would by default not give access to any packages outside that env, not even the ones installed in the system directory (such a feature is being added in https://github.com/sdispater/poetry/issues/1393 which I think implies the default behavior is the opposite). Developing altair_recipes https://github.com/piccolbo/altair_recipes/ I had a couple of instances where I forgot to add a new dep to pyproject.toml, tests succeeded locally but failed on travis on loading that package. The situation is promptly fixed by adding the dependency with poetry add. Most recent example, I started using hypothesis for some tests, forgot to add it, everything worked locally, went for release, fail. Added as dev dep, pass local, pass remote, done ( see https://travis-ci.org/piccolbo/altair_recipes build 102 and 103). The only theory I have is that the local testing was able to pick up the system installation of that package. The tests are run with `poetry run py.test` With the goal of having local tests match  tests done in a CI setting in a fresh environment, what can I do to have the local env best match the CI env? And is isolation from the system installation really the problem? Thanks

Comment: Are you setting `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @jpyams No and 15 more characters to satisfy the SO AI

Comment: Are you running your tests with `poetry run`?

Comment: Yes and 12 more characters to appease SO gods.

Answer (score 0):

> The only theory I have is that the local testing was able to pick up the system installation of that package.

Given my personal experience with packaging in python, I'd assume that this is the underlying reason. Now, there are a long-term and a short-term solution to this problem:

Long-term you should adopt the mindset of never installing python packages that are tied to a single project system wide. This includes dev-dependencies like `pytest` or in your case `hypothesis` - uninstall them. `poetry` is one of the very few python packages that are relevant system wide and should be installed as such. Additionally a side note, this is why the recommended way to install `poetry` is not `pip` but [`get-poetry.py`](https://poetry.eustace.io/docs/#installation).

Short-term, you can set up your virtual environment by hand with `virtualenv`, which [blocks global site-packages by default](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/#cmdoption-no-site-packages) (but it is likely that the envs that `poetry` build have the same default setting). To enforce execution of locally installed packages you can either set the execution path before running tests:

```sh
$ PATH=$(dirname $(poetry run which python)) pytest
```

If you have activated the virtual env (which you can do by running `poetry shell`) you can also run the tools as python modules:

```sh
(env)$ python -m pytest
```

Comment: Setting `PYTHONPATH` doesn't exclude system packages, it just adds other paths to the front of your `sys.path`

Comment: @jpyams ha, that as quite confusing of me. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Sorry, I came here because poetry points to here to get support. Your suggestions may be good,  but I am looking for poetry support, not to use other programs or remove other packages. SO is a very noisy place to use as support channel.

Comment: I did try to answer your question. The thing is, you cant solve that problem with poetry alone, poetry cant control where your system looks for executables. Do my suggestions not work?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing bug https://github.com/sdispater/poetry/issues/571
I need 8 more characters to post this. Clearly SO and don't share the same opinion on conciseness.